# TestCafe: await t.expect(Selector().exists).ok() sporadically throwing a TypeError

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there any possible reason for `await t.expect(Selector().exists).ok()` to throw `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`? It happens sporadically so it's hard to track down but my understanding is that if the Selector is not present in the DOM tree then it should wait the timeout and throw an expected boolean to be boolean if not found error. I know I'm not providing much to go on but I'm unable to reproduce the issue on a production facing website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is on version 1.18.3 of TestCafe but I'm uncertain if it happens in other versions as well.

Comment: Showing the full test or chunk of code would be helpful. For instance, maybe you aren't wrapping it in an `async` function

Comment: So I get the sporadic failure in multiple places but recently it failed within this expect call:

`await t.expect(Selector('[data-ig-id="abeImg"]').exists).ok()`

All page logic exists in their own page models.

Comment: We have assertionTimeout and selectorTimeout set to 20000 each in our .testcaferc.json file.

Comment: Additionally, this check happens after we've switched to an iFrame, which succeeds. The full test would be difficult to share as we have some pretty complex logic around the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't discover the root cause of the failure, wrapping the expect methods in a retry has completely eliminated the error. I'll update this topic if I get any additional information around the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find the cause of the issue without a test code example. Could you please insert the [t.wait](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402672/reference/test-api/testcontroller/wait) method with a big timeout before each potential problematic place, e.g.

`await t.expect(Selector().exists).ok()` ?

Then, observe how the tests are passed to see if the issue depends on the timeout.

Please pay attention to the following information from [Selector Timeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements#selector-timeout):

> Selector timeouts have no effect on Selector.exists and Selector.count
> properties. These properties are evaluated immediately regardless of a
> timeout. To apply a timeout to exists and count assertions, pass the
> timeout to the assertion method (expect.ok, expect.eql, etc.).
> If the issue depends on the timeout, please share a small test code snippet where the problem is reproduced.

If the problem is reproduced independently from the timeout, this means that the issue is in another part of your code.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try passing timeouts to the assertion functions.

Comment: Sadly no luck, even with passing in a large timeout to the ok() function. I'm just going to try a wrapper function to retry in cases of TypeErrors.